# Bash - remove all lines beginning with 'P'

Tags: windows-7, bash, cygwin

I have a text file that's about 300KB in size. I want to remove all lines from this file that begin with the letter "P". This is what I've been using:

```
> cat file.txt | egrep -v P*
```

That isn't outputting to console. I can use cat on the file without another other commands and it prints out fine. My final intention being to:

```
> cat file.txt | egrep -v P* > new.txt
```

No error appears, it just doesn't print anything out and if I run the 2nd command, new.txt is empty.

edit: I should say I'm running Windows 7 with Cygwin installed.

Comment: no need to `cat file | grep pattern`... `grep pattern file` is doing fine on is own...

Answer (score 2):

Try this command instead:

```
cat file.txt | egrep -v '^P*' > new.txt
```

An alternative that avoids the [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html) would be:

```
egrep -v '^P*' file.txt > new.txt
```

You need to put quotes around your regexes in egrep, otherwise bash will expand them (in your case, the `*` glob would expand to every file in the current directory beginning with an uppercase P).

Comment: [Obligatory "useless use of cat is a silly complaint" complaint.]

Answer (score 0):

`P*` as a regex means "any number of `P`s, including 0". So it will always match, since every line contains at least 0 `P`s. That explains why `egrep -v P*` prints nothing: every line matches, and `-v` selects the lines which don't match. (Actually, it might do something else, since `P*` will be expanded by bash into the list of files starting with the letter `P` in the current directory, if there happen to be any. You should use quotes `egrep -v "P*"`, but that's not your problem.)

You want to match one `P` at the beginning of the line. So you need to specify that the regex is "anchored" (only matches at the beginning), which you do by putting a `^` at the beginning:

```
grep -v ^P file.txt > new.txt
```

By the way, `egrep` is deprecated; you should use `grep -E`, but in this case there's no difference between basic and extended regex.

`grep` does not use "globs", it uses regular expressions. And it does not force the regular expression to match the entire line; it's sufficient if a string matching the regular expression appears somewhere in the line.